# im setting a background-image but its not showing unless i specify the height in pixels or vh

Tags: html, css, reactjs, background-image

i am using reactjs and in my main page container i am setting a background image as such:

```
.opening-container {
  background-image: url("../../images/sadaqashdbg.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

and the opening-container is the main div and includes all the elements on the page, however when the bg image is not showing, and when i put height:100% it still does not show, but when i put height:1200px; or height:100vh it starts showing but not covering whole page also

example:

```
<div className='opening-container'>
<button></button>
<button></button>
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After you have done that, edit your question to meet those guidelines and to include a [minimal, reproduciable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including your HTML aswell.

Comment: what's the content of your `opening-container` element? An element will have a size of 0 if there is no content (and a background-image is not content, it's just a background)

Comment: the opening-container has buttons and texts

Comment: Have you tried ``width: auto;``  for the ``.opening-container``?

Comment: its not about the width but the height, and yes i tried it @RohitMittal

Comment: tried ``background-size: auto;`` instead of ``cover``?

Comment: yup tried that too, however i think the problem is that the opening-container is not full screen, like even though i have elements in it, it is taking a with of 0, that's what i think idk, and idk how to fix it @RohitMittal

Answer (score 0):

The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly.
so you should specify your parent box height or use vh or px.

Comment: hey thank you, however the containing box has elements inside, shouldn't the height be automatically set